# Determinant of a 3*3 matrix of cosines

Tags: matrices, determinant

I need help in evaluating the following determinant:
$$\begin{vmatrix} 
\cos\frac{2\pi}{63} & \cos\frac{3\pi}{90} & \cos\frac{4\pi}{77} \\
\cos\frac{\pi}{72} & \cos\frac{\pi}{40} & \cos\frac{3\pi}{88} \\
1 & \cos\frac{\pi}{90} & \cos\frac{2\pi}{99} 
\end{vmatrix}$$

I noticed that there is a pattern in the right row ($\frac{4\pi}{77}$,$\frac{3\pi}{88}$ & $\frac{2\pi}{99}$) but I don't know how to utilize the pattern. I also don't see any other patterns: subtracting or adding two rows seems pointless and would further complicate an already complicated determinant.

Is there any way of evaluating this determinant?

Comment: Maybe it can help to notice that the matrix can also be written as: $$\begin{vmatrix} 
\cos\frac{2\pi}{7*9} & \cos\frac{3\pi}{9*10} & \cos\frac{4\pi}{7*11} \\ \cos\frac{\pi}{8*9} & \cos\frac{2\pi}{8*10} & \cos\frac{3\pi}{8*11} \\ \cos\frac{0\pi}{9*9} & \cos\frac{\pi}{9*10} & \cos\frac{2\pi}{9*11} \end{vmatrix}$$ (are you sure btw the second term is not $cos(3Pi/70)$?)

Comment: @Jeanba In that case the determinant equals zero.

Comment: I would first try it with some math software, and based on the result,  try to find a clever way of doing it.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, can't see it right away, is this so obvious?

Comment: @Jeanba Not up to now, but my CAS told me so :)

Comment: I think I've got something: if the matrix to be analyzed is the one with cos(3Pi/70) terms then each term can be expressed by:  cos(((2+j-i)Pi)/((7+i)(9+j)))=cos(((2+7+j-i-7)Pi)/((7+i)(9+j))) which can be reduced  to $cos(\frac{\pi}{7+i}-\frac{\pi}{9+j})$ ((i,j) being the rows and columns indices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume the second entry to be $\cos(3\pi/70)$.

Multiply the last row by $-\cos(\pi/72)$ and add it the the second row; multiply the last row by $-\cos(2\pi/63)$ and add it to the first row. Then use Laplace expansion to obtain
$$\begin{vmatrix}
-\cos(\frac{\pi}{90}) \cos(\frac{\pi}{72}) + 
  \cos(\frac{\pi}{40})& -\cos(\frac{\pi}{72}) \cos(\frac{2 \pi}{99}) + \cos(\frac{3 \pi}{88})\\
 -\cos(\frac{\pi}{90}) \cos(\frac{2 \pi}{63}) + 
  \cos(\frac{3 \pi}{70}) & -\cos(\frac{2 \pi}{99}) 
\cos(\frac{2 \pi}{63}) +   \cos(\frac{4 \pi}{77})
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Key observation is that each entry is of the form $-\cos(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x+y)$. But the latter sum equals $\sin(x)\sin(y)$. Hence we have
$$\begin{vmatrix}
\sin(\pi/90) \sin(\pi/72)& \sin(\pi/72) \sin(2 \pi/99)\\
 \sin(\pi/90) \sin(2 \pi/63) & \sin(2 \pi/99) \sin(2 \pi/63) 
\end{vmatrix},
$$
which is trivially zero.

Answer (score 0):

I tried WhatsUp's suggestion and evaluated the following using maple: the answer was:
$$-0.0000098824$$

On replacing the middle term with $cos(\frac {3\pi}{70})$ and evaluating, the answer comes out to be zero, which corresponds with the answer mentioned. This is, unfortunately, a printing mistake :P

Thank you to all for their advice.

Comment: so to be sure, which was the true matrix to be analyzed, the one with cos(3π/70) or the one you first proposed? I think what is interesting in this question is much more the methodology than the computed answer.